# I cannot create more than three resource files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resx

I have asp.net c# webform project, I managed two languages however when I add third and fourth resx file like;

[image: image 1]

it is still ok when I run the website on localhost, but, when I transfer it via FTP to the server I get this error,
[image: Error image]

any suggestions?

Comment: you have to transfer the .dll that has been created in bin folder with language code

Comment: There is no .dill file created in bin folder. By the way I transfer the whole project.

Comment: Can you please translate the error message in English?

Comment: @Cosmin "Res" is defined in "Resource" already.